# CMake how to link subproject with external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following Structure of my Project:

```
CMakeLists.txt
cmake
  CMakeLists.txt
src
  server
  CMakeLists.txt
    impl
      server.cpp
    CMakeLitst.txt
    main.cpp
```

I am trying to include subproject [src](https://github.com/qicosmos/ormpp/tree/master/lang/english) that's depends in my case on PostgreSQL.
Cmake is configuring fine, but building **subproject** with error:
`libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory`.

`PostgreSQL`  is finding ok and linking without subproject  good.

These are the current CMakeLists.txt Files:

`cmake/CmakeLists.txt:`

```
FetchContent_Declare(ormpp
             GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/qicosmos/ormpp.git
             GIT_TAG        6f4f9dcb07487a4a7273eb9fa0d7535f6adf6963)


FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ormpp)
```

`CMakeLists.txt:`

```
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(cmake)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`src/server/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
add_executable(server main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(server PUBLIC PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL)
```

What do I have to change in my `CMakeFiles`  to get subproject linking to work properly?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What does the line of code look like which `#include`s libpq-fe.h?  And what directory contains that file on your system?

Comment: @John Zwinck #include <libpq-fe.h> and D:\postgreSQL\postgresql\include\libpq-fe.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
target_include_directories(server SYSTEM "D:\postgreSQL\postgresql\include")
```

Or this, if you have multiple targets and just want to specify it once:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM "D:\postgreSQL\postgresql\include")
```

Ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html